# Inner joins on SQL multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join

I've got 2 tables in my SQL database:

```
**teams**
id
name
country

**games**
id
date
hometeamid (hometeam country)
awayteamid (awayteam country)
score
```

Now i want to get the games with all their data, but instead of getting hometeamid's I want to get their names and countries by getting them from the teams table by some sort of inner join.

Anyone know how to get 4 variables in 1 query by id from another table (team)?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  And `JOIN` again.

Comment: This is a join didn't they cover this in the book / class on sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should join the table team two time one for hometeam and one for awayteam

```
select g.date, g.hometeamid, t1.name hometeam, t2.name  awayteam
from games g 
inner join teams t1 on g.hometeamid = t1.id
INNER JOIN teams t2 on g.hometeamid = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from games inner join teams on games.hometeamid = teams.id;
```

This will create a table that matches each team to each game that exists. If there is a game without the team OR a team without a game, they will be omitted since INNER JOIN needs both to match.

Comment: Simple said: I want all information from the games, but instead of the hometeamid i want the home team name and awayteamid the awayteam name.